# All sub-apps in Magnolia do not open and produce errors

Tags: magnolia

I have several Magnolia CE core instances on Tomcat. Suddenly one instance set as public stopped functioning. I can log in and open any app, but if I try to open the sub app eg. add page, edit page, manage users. I get an error in a red bar:
Sub-app failed to start: (name_of sub-app)
Failed to create instance of (sub-app class)

The webapp was deployed from a maven jar.
The jars are identical to another deployment functioning correctly.
Tomcat configuration did not change.

What could be the error and where can I start to troubleshoot?

below is the start of the error (full error is to long for SO):

```
    2020-03-29 21:22:21,214 ERROR agnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl: Sub-app [detail] of app [pages] failed
     to start
    info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to create instance of [class info.magnolia.pages.app.edit
    or.PagesEditorSubApp]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProv
    ider.java:138) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.lambda$newInstanceWithParameterResolvers$4(UiC
    ontextBoundComponentProvider.java:135) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.provideInCurrentScope(UiContextBoundComponentP
    rovider.java:163) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(UiContextBou
    ndComponentProvider.java:135) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ViewComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(ViewComponentProvider.
    java:81) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.newInstance(UiContextBoundComponentProvider.ja
    va:130) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl.startSubApp(AppInstanceControllerImpl.java:398) ~[ma
    gnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl.openSubApp(AppInstanceControllerImpl.java:346) ~[mag
    nolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.BaseApp.locationChanged(BaseApp.java:65) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppInstanceControllerImpl.onLocationUpdate(AppInstanceControllerImpl.java:222)
     ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppControllerImpl.doStartIfNotAlreadyRunning(AppControllerImpl.java:246) ~[mag
    nolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.AppControllerImpl.onLocationChanged(AppControllerImpl.java:365) ~[magnolia-ui-
    framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
           .....
....
....
    ider.java:134) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            ... 135 more
    Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

    1) Error in custom provider, info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to create instance of [class
     info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.PageEditorPresenter]
      at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.DeflateUiContextDependentBindings.bindNonAbstractType(DeflateUiContextDependentBindi
    ngs.java:204) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComp
    onentProviderBuilder$1 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$CombinedModule -> info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.DeflateUiConte
    xtDependentBindings)
      while locating info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.PageEditorPresenter annotated with info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SubApp
    Impl@7510210d
      at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.DeflateUiContextDependentBindings.lambda$configure$8(DeflateUiContextDependentBindin
    gs.java:189) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceCompo
    nentProviderBuilder$1 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$CombinedModule -> info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.DeflateUiContex
    tDependentBindings)
      while locating info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.PageEditorPresenter

    1 error
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:22
    6) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1053) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceParameterResolver.resolveParameter(GuiceParameterResolver.java:90) ~[m
    agnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameter(ObjectManufacturer.java:160) ~[magnolia-core-
    6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameters(ObjectManufacturer.java:140) ~[magnolia-core
    -6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:91) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.
    jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProv
    ider.java:134) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            ... 135 more
    Caused by: info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to create instance of [class info.magnolia.pag
    es.app.editor.PageEditorPresenter]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProv
    ider.java:138) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.lambda$newInstanceWithParameterResolvers$4(UiC
    ontextBoundComponentProvider.java:135) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.provideInCurrentScope(UiContextBoundComponentP
    rovider.java:163) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(UiContextBou
    ndComponentProvider.java:135) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ViewComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(ViewComponentProvider.
    java:81) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.newInstance(UiContextBoundComponentProvider.ja
    va:130) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider$CreateNewInstanceWithComponentProvide
    r.newInstance(ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider.java:115) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider.lambda$null$0(ProduceNewInstancesWith
    ComponentProvider.java:84) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85) ~[guice-4.2.2.j
    ar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdap
    ter.java:57) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:59) ~[guice-4.2.2
    .jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.ja
    va:47) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) ~[g
    uice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SessionStoreScope.lambda$getInstanceFromBeanStore$1(SessionStoreScope.java:73)
     ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SessionStoreScope.getInstanceFromBeanStore(SessionStoreScope.java:72) ~[magnol
    ia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SessionStoreScope.lambda$scope$0(SessionStoreScope.java:64) ~[magnolia-ui-fram
    ework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39) ~[g
    uice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1081) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextApplyingProvider.get(UiContextApplyingProvider.java:111) ~[magnolia-u
    i-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85) ~[guice-4.2.2.j
    ar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdap
    ter.java:57) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:59) ~[guice-4.2.2
    .jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.ja
    va:47) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceParameterResolver.resolveParameter(GuiceParameterResolver.java:90) ~[m
    agnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameter(ObjectManufacturer.java:160) ~[magnolia-core-
    6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameters(ObjectManufacturer.java:140) ~[magnolia-core
    -6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:91) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.
    jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProv
    ider.java:134) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            ... 135 more
    Caused by: info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to resolve param [5] of type [interface info.m
    agnolia.pages.app.editor.parameters.PageEditorStatus]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameters(ObjectManufacturer.java:146) ~[magnolia-core
    -6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:91) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.
    jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProv
    ider.java:134) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.lambda$newInstanceWithParameterResolvers$4(UiC
    ontextBoundComponentProvider.java:135) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.provideInCurrentScope(UiContextBoundComponentP
    rovider.java:163) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(UiContextBou
    ndComponentProvider.java:135) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ViewComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(ViewComponentProvider.
    java:81) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextBoundComponentProvider.newInstance(UiContextBoundComponentProvider.ja
    va:130) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider$CreateNewInstanceWithComponentProvide
    r.newInstance(ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider.java:115) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider.lambda$null$0(ProduceNewInstancesWith
    ComponentProvider.java:84) ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85) ~[guice-4.2.2.j
    ar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdap
    ter.java:57) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:59) ~[guice-4.2.2
    .jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.ja
    va:47) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) ~[g
    uice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SessionStoreScope.lambda$getInstanceFromBeanStore$1(SessionStoreScope.java:73)
     ~[magnolia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SessionStoreScope.getInstanceFromBeanStore(SessionStoreScope.java:72) ~[magnol
    ia-ui-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.SessionStoreScope.lambda$scope$0(SessionStoreScope.java:64) ~[magnolia-ui-fram
    ework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39) ~[g
    uice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1081) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
            at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.UiContextApplyingProvider.get(UiContextApplyingProvider.java:111) ~[magnolia-u
    i-framework-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85) ~[guice-4.2.2.j
    ar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdap
    ter.java:57) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:59) ~[guice-4.2.2
    .jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.ja
    va:47) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050) ~[guice-4.2.2.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceParameterResolver.resolveParameter(GuiceParameterResolver.java:90) ~[m
    agnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameter(ObjectManufacturer.java:160) ~[magnolia-core-
    6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.resolveParameters(ObjectManufacturer.java:140) ~[magnolia-core
    -6.1.4.jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.ObjectManufacturer.newInstance(ObjectManufacturer.java:91) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.
    jar:?]
            at info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceComponentProvider.newInstanceWithParameterResolvers(GuiceComponentProv
    ider.java:134) ~[magnolia-core-6.1.4.jar:?]
            ... 135 more
    Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

    1) Error in custom provider, info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to create instance of [class
     info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.parameters.DefaultPageEditorStatus]
      at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider.lambda$null$2(ProduceNewInstancesWithCompon
    entProvider.java:84) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.Gu
    iceComponentProviderBuilder$1 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$CombinedModule -> info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.Deflate
    UiContextDependentBindings -> info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.ProduceNewInstancesWithComponentProvider)
      while locating info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.parameters.DefaultPageEditorStatus
      while locating info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.parameters.PageEditorStatus annotated with info.magnolia.ui.framework.io
    c.SubAppImpl@7510210d
      at info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.DeflateUiContextDependentBindings.lambda$configure$8(DeflateUiContextDependentBindin
    gs.java:189) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> info.magnolia.objectfactory.guice.GuiceCompo
    nentProviderBuilder$1 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$CombinedModule -> info.magnolia.ui.framework.ioc.DeflateUiContex
    tDependentBindings)
      while locating info.magnolia.pages.app.editor.parameters.PageEditorStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

The hint is in the log itself, check this line out:

```
  Caused by: info.magnolia.objectfactory.MgnlInstantiationException: Failed to resolve param [5] of type [interface info.m
  agnolia.pages.app.editor.parameters.PageEditorStatus]
```

It is one of those cases that it should never have had happened. I assume you have custom code running somewhere, I'd check the bindings are correct and the rest will be pure debugging, unfortunately. Is there anything specific I can answer for you?

Cheers,